# Create rank column, providing "=" prefix for equal values, in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am looking to create a formula that gives the rank of a list of pre-ordered numbers, but sets the ranking of equal values to the appropriate rank with "=" before it. I am using Google Sheets, but I imagine any potential solution is likely to work in Excel?

So, if there's a list of 5 numbers:

```
**Values**
10
8
8
6
4
```

They will have a Rank column:

```
**Rank**    **Values**
  1             10
  =2            8
  =2            8
  4             6
  5             4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A, A1:A)>1=FALSE,
 IF(A1:A<>"", RANK(A1:A, INDIRECT("A1:A")), ), "="&
 IF(A1:A<>"", RANK(A1:A, INDIRECT("A1:A")), )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to create =2. I don't know ant spreadsheet that will accept that. A `=2 will work as it is treated as a string. If you will just take the ranking RANK works well (it will return 2). If your values are in column A without a Header, place this in B1.

=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"",RANK(A1:A,indirect("A1:A")),""))